# Guardar CSV sin la columna de enumeración

Tags: python, csv

Tengo un df y necesito guardarlo en csv. No hay problema en hacerlo. Sin embargo, cuando se guarda, automáticamente aparece en el archivo la columna de enumeración.

Os muestro como queda cuando abro el csv en excel:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como veis, tengo 2 columnas (User_screen_name y Mention), pero antes del User_screen_name aparecen los números que indican la posición de la fila.

¿Cómo puedo guardar en csv en python sin que aparezca esta enumeración? 
Imagino que tengo que agregar algún parámetro a:

```
df.to_csv("ruta/archivo.csv")
```

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda

Un saludo,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estás tratando de guardar sin el índice, prueba con lo siguiente:

```
df.to_csv("ruta/archivo.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias Adrián!